# How to convert a `id<MTLCommandQueue>` to a `MTL::CommandQueue` of Metal-Cpp?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, metal

**The situation:** I'm developing an iOS Metal App in **Objective-C**. I need to use a 3rd-party library [VkFFT](https://github.com/DTolm/VkFFT) that provides Metal FFTs based on [Metal-Cpp](https://github.com/bkaradzic/metal-cpp).

**What I need:** pass a `id<MTLCommandQueue>` instance from Objective-C world to C++ world as a `MTL::CommandQueue` object so that I can push compute commands to it. **I don't want to create a seperate commmand queue in Metal-Cpp** because using a single command queue can let me keep pushing all commands to it without `waitUntilCompleted`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of both [Hamid Yusifli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76994555/8102500) and [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/DTolm/VkFFT/issues/131#issuecomment-1697203936), I solved my problem.

1. From Objective-C code (`.m`), cast the `id<MTLCommandQueue>` into `void*`:

   ```objectivec
   id<MTLCommandQueue> objcQueue = /* Your Objective-c queue */;
   void* commandQueuePtr = (__bridge void*)objcQueue;
   ```
2. Pass this opaque pointer to C++ world.
3. In C++ code, "decode" the `void*` back to a `MTL::CommandQueue*`:

   ```c
   void foo(void* commandQueuePtr) {
     MTL::CommandQueue* commandQueue = (MTL::CommandQueue*) commandQueuePtr;
     // submit GPU works to commandQueue...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

[Bridged casts](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id15)

> A bridged cast is a C-style cast annotated with one of three keywords:
>
> - (__bridge T) op casts the operand to the destination type T. If T is a
>   retainable object pointer type, then op must have a non-retainable
>   pointer type. If T is a non-retainable pointer type, then op must have
>   a retainable object pointer type. Otherwise the cast is ill-formed.
>   There is no transfer of ownership, and ARC inserts no retain
>   operations.
> - (__bridge_retained T) op casts the operand, which must
>   have retainable object pointer type, to the destination type, which
>   must be a non-retainable pointer type. ARC retains the value, subject
>   to the usual optimizations on local values, and the recipient is
>   responsible for balancing that +1.
> - (__bridge_transfer T) op casts the
>   operand, which must have non-retainable pointer type, to the
>   destination type, which must be a retainable object pointer type. ARC
>   will release the value at the end of the enclosing full-expression,
>   subject to the usual optimizations on local values. These casts are
>   required in order to transfer objects in and out of ARC control; see
>   the rationale in the section on conversion of retainable object
>   pointers.

> Using a __bridge_retained or __bridge_transfer cast purely to convince ARC > to emit an unbalanced retain or release, respectively, is poor form.

```
id<MTLCommandQueue> objcQueue = /* Your Objective-c queue */;
MTL::CommandQueue* queue = (__bridge MTL::CommandQueue*)objcQueue;
```

Comment: Thank you! With your help, I solved my problem. But I wrote another answer myself which I think would be more appropriate to be the accepted answer.